# mysql length of word index and word quantity doesn't match?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, text-processing

i made a final project of information retrieval

so i need to get this solved quickly

let's say i have a word list in python like this

```
word = ['tugas', 'akhir', 'implementasi', 'algoritma', 'klastering', 'ada',......]
```

the length of the list is 125

then i make a new list to input the indexes of the word list above in `ids`.

The code is like this:

```
sql = """SELECT id_term FROM abstract_terms WHERE term IN %s"""
pram = [word]
cursor.execute(sql, pram)
ids = list()
ids.extend(cursor.fetchall())
```

but the length of `ids` list and `word` list are not same so that if i want to insert the id of the term which `ids` contains, i always get error `list index is out of range`

can you tell me what mistakes i did? please help :(

Answer (score 0):

SQL's `WHERE col IN values` syntax looks like this

```
 WHERE col IN ('tugas', 'akhir', 'implementasi', 'algoritma', 'klastering')
```

Your python code needs to construct a query with text like that.  It's generally a pain in the neck, but it's possible.